# Include Perl in Java

Tags: java, perl, include

Is there any way to execute perl code without having to use Runtime.getRuntime.exec("..."); (parse in java app)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been looking into this myself recently. The most promising thing I've found thus far is the [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Java) module on CPAN. It allows calling Java from Perl but also (via some included Java classes) calling Perl from Java.

Comment: are you sure about this: **can you do the reverse: calling perl from Java** , is it reliable in mission critical stuff?

Answer (score 4):

[this](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=373839) looks like what you're asking for

Answer (score 4):

[Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java/) provides an [embedded Perl interpreter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java/Java/PerlInterpreter/PerlInterpreter.pod) in a class.  You can use this to call Perl code from your Java code.

[Graciliano M. Passos' PLJava](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PLJava-0.04/README.pod) also provides an embedded interpreter.

Don't use JPL (Java Perl Lingo)--the project is dead and has been removed from modern perls.

Answer (score 2):

`Inline::Perl` is the accepted way. But there's also [Jerl](https://freecode.com/projects/jerl) which may be run from a JAR.

Here's [an example](https://code.google.com/p/jerl/source/browse/src/exampleUsage.java) without using the VM wrapper (which is not so fun).

Here's some examples using the `jerlWrapper` class to make it easier to code:

```
import jerlWrapper.perlVM;

public final class HelloWorld  {

    /* keeping it simple */
    private static String helloWorldPerl = "print 'Hello World '.$].\"\n\";";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        perlVM helloJavaPerl = new perlVM(helloWorldPerl);  
        helloJavaPerl.run();
    }
}
```

or

```
import jerlWrapper.perlVM;

public final class TimeTest  {

    /*  The (ugly) way to retrieve time within perl, with all the
     *  extra addition to make it worth reading afterwards.
     */
    private static String testProggie = new String(
            "my ($sec, $min, $hr, $day, $mon, $year) = localtime;"+
            "printf(\"%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d\n\", "+
            "       $mon, $day + 1, 1900 + $year, $hr, $min, $sec);"
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        perlVM helloJavaPerl = new perlVM(testProggie);     
        boolean isSuccessful = helloJavaPerl.run();
        if (isSuccessful) {
            System.out.print(helloJavaPerl.getOutput());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jerl for Perl5 is being deprecated.  Rakudo perl has VM options going forward: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakudo_Perl_6

Comment: Jerl for Perl5 is indeed deprecated. While the project was stable for 2 years+, there are better virtualization options.

Answer (score 1):

I could have sworn it was easy as pie using the [Java Scripting API](https://scripting.dev.java.net/).
But apparently it's not on the list of existing implementations...

<strike>So, maybe this helps instead :
[java and perl](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Misc/perl-5.6.1/jpl/docs/Tutorial.html#2.1.1%20calling%20perl%20from%20java)</strike>

*edit: i said "maybe"*

Comment: The JPL is dead.  Don't use it. Inline::Java is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe this exists.  While there have been several languages ported to the JVM (JRuby, Jython etc) Perl is not yet one of them.