# How do I execute an external program from Java?

Tags: java, ipc

Possible duplicates:

- [How should I call a Perl Script in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603554/how-should-i-call-a-perl-script-in-java)
- [Include Perl in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971215/include-perl-in-java)
- [How can I call Perl from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274840/how-can-i-call-perl-from-java)

---

I want to execute a program of Perl from Java.

I take a file name with an argument and carry out a program, and the program of Perl outputs a result file.

So it is the program side of the JAVA

1. I appoint an argument and carry out Perl program
2. Perl program reads the file which I spitted out

2) checks the existence of the file and seems to be able to do it, but will 1) be possible? ActivePerl is installed with the present machine. I develop Java on Eclipse.

Comment: Please stop calling it "JAVA" - it's not an acronym, the programming language is called "Java".

Comment: "JAVA" is almost as annoying as people saying "PERL"

Comment: I thought JAVA was a recursive acronym that makes reference to the virtual machine: Java Ain't a Vacuum-tube Appliance.  ;)

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
String command = "ls";    
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Reference:[Executing a Command](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html)

FYI: The link contains examples of commands with arguments, and with spaces too.