# How do I execute a perl script in java?

Tags: java, perl

How do I use java to execute a perl script. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I call a Perl Script in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603554/how-should-i-call-a-perl-script-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without knowing any more of the requirements:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/perl /path/to/perl/script");`

Documentation about `Runtime.exec`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)

Comment: Adding to answer -- You may want to use newer api -- ProcessBuilder. Passing arguments, processing out/err streams etc are better in this API