# Invoking a perl script from java

Tags: java, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I call a Perl Script in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603554/how-should-i-call-a-perl-script-in-java)

Hi,

I am currently working on a project that needs to invoke a perl script from java.  Is there a way by which I can get the output of a Perl script in the java program I am running? I have tried different ways by which it can be done but I couldn't get a conclusive answer.  I am working on a windows machine.

Thanks!!

Comment: Many questions have already been answered on SO. Please use the search before asking a question, you may find your answer instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Google [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class and example of its usage. Get output stream of the Process -- which is inputStream for java process, so process.getInputStream() -- this is your Perl script output.