# Need help -- Pass two params in java in command line through perl

Tags: java, perl

I need to pass two params in a java file similar as I pass  from command line.

Something like

```
$ENV{classpath} = ".\\my.jar;$ENV{classpath}";
system("$ENV{JAVA_HOME}\\bin\\java com.myclass  param1  param2"  );
```

how can i achieve this in a perl script?

Comment: Are you looking for Java or Javascript solution?

Comment: java only. Removing javascript tag.

Comment: seems you are looking for a perl script, not a java solution.

Comment: yes i need help in writting a perl script to do the same..

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/603607/1737813

Comment: Thanks Bosko, BUT it is all about calling perl in java. I need to call java in perl with runtime args.. I did not get any proper info on search,

Comment: @bosko-mijin, I suppose OP wants to call Java from Perl, not the opposite way round...

Comment: @smriti: It looks to me like your original code should work. What problems are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to my work system still let me give it a try. It should work for you.

```
my $cpJava=" -cp /your/classpath";
my $myClass="your class name";
my $runMe="Java path ".$cpJava." ".$myClass." ".join(' ', @ARGV);
```

`@ARGV` will have all your parameters. Learn more about `join` from [here](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-join.html).

Then use system:

```
system($runMe);
```

Hope it would work for you.

Comment: Wow Nik. Thank you soo much. So if i want to pass two params i can @ARGV = ("param1", "param2"); and pass.. thanks

Comment: But what @Nik has given you is, effectively, no different from what you had originally. He's just building up the string before passing it to `system`.

Comment: `my $runMe = "Java path $cpJava $myClass @ARGV";` - this does the same thing too. Perl interpolates variables in a double-quoted string.